# zip recursively each file in a dir, where the name of the file has spaces in it

Tags: sh

I am quite stuck; I need to compress the content of a folder, where I have multiple files (extension .dat). I went for shell scripting.

So far I told myself that is not that hard: I just need to recursively read the content of the dir, get the name of the file and zip it, using the name of the file itself.

This is what I wrote:

```
for i in *.dat; do zip $i".zip" $i; done
```

Now when I try it I get a weird behavior: each file is called like "12/23/2012 data102 test1.dat"; and when I run this sequence of commands; I see that zip instead of recognizing the whole file name, see each part of the string as single entity, causing the whole operation to fail.

I told myself that I was doing something wrong, and that the i variable was wrong; so I have replaced echo, instead than the zip command (to see which one was the output of the i variable); and the $i output is the full name of the file, not part of it.

I am totally clueless at this point about what is going on...if the variable i is read by zip it reads each single piece of the string, instead of the whole thing, while if I use echo to see the content of that variable it gets the correct output.

Do I have to pass the value of the filename to zip in a different way? Since it is the content of a variable passed as parameter I was assuming that it won't matter if the string is one or has spaces in it, and I can't find in the man page the answer (if there is any in there).

Anyone knows why do I get this behavior and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `echo` is a lousy diagnostic.

Comment: I know; same as the print statement in many languages, but I do not know how to print a value of a variable while running in a shell script loop...there is no IDE that you can pause and check values.

Comment: No, the basic approach is fine, but `echo` has unwanted and/or misleading effects. Try `printf` or your own Perl one-liner to print the individual values of `ARGV`. "The most effective debugging tool is still careful thought, coupled with judiciously placed print statements." -- Brian W. Kernighan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote anything with spaces in it.

```
zip "$i.zip" "$i"
```

Generally speaking, any variable interpolation should have double quotes unless you specifically require the shell to split it into multiple tokens. The internal field separator `$IFS` defaults to space and tab, but you can change it to make the shell do word splitting on arbitrary separators. See any decent beginners' shell tutorial for a detailed account of the shell's quoting mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation...I just assumed that passing $varname would not tokenize it.

I was hitting my head on the wall; now I get it, Thanks!!!!!